# ERROR in Cannot read property 'flattenedMappings' of null when upgraded from angular 8 to angular 9?

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular9

ERROR in Cannot read property 'flattenedMappings' of null when upgraded from angular 8 to angular 9

Comment: Please provide some code, otherwise there is no chance we can help you.
Besides, obviously the object you want to run `flattenedMappings` on is `null`, thus the error pops up. So just add a check and only if it's truthy run `flattenedMappings` on it.

Comment: Need code to see what is wrong.

Comment: Getting the same error after upgrading from Angular8 to 9.0.3. Upgrading to 9.0.1 works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

try angular 9.0.2, i have this problem after update to 9.0.3